# Drupal permissions: create, edit, published content per role

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, user-permissions

I've looking around the internet for a module (Drupal 7) which helps to set the create/edit/publish permissions. I can't find a module which does the following:

- Verified users can create own unpublished content.
- Verified users can NOT publish any or own content.
- Administrators can create, edit and publish any content, no matter it's published or not.
- When the content is published, verified users can edit their own, but it will automaticly unpublished.

For example: A kind of blog where everyone can post, but it has to be verified by an administrator. After changing the content, it has to be verified again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can use Drupal's own features for almost all of the tasks you need:

1 - If you give authenticated users create content permissions and you check out the "published" checkbox in your contet types' settings they can create upublished content;

2 - Authenticated users normally have no administer nodes permission, so they cannot publish their own content (or any);

3 - Administrators can do everything they want, provided they have administer nodes permission.

4 - You can set edit own content to authenticated users.

You need one more trick to unpublish content when it is edited. I don't know of any contrib module providing this functionality, but you can easily add it to your custom module, e.g.:

```
function <YOUR_MODULE_NAME>_node_presave($node) {
  if (! user_access("administer nodes")) { // skip if user has admmin permission
    $node->status = 0; // unpublish the node
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I'll try the 3 first solutions. For the last issue, I've set up a rule which unpublish content when it's editted by an authenticated user, so I dont have to make a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Like parnatt said, you can do just about all of this using admin/people/permissions. Look under Node section.

For a more detail workflow solution, take a look at Workbench and its submodules like [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation).

Comment: Thanks for the idea to use Workbench Moderation. I'll definitely use this :)